# Why this code $results = \Db::select('select * from engegraph_forms_membros where id = ?', [1]); dont work?

Tags: database, octobercms

I have this code on my component.

```
$results = \Db::select('select * from engegraph_forms_membros where id = ?', [1]);
echo $results;
```

but i have this error 
**"Array to string conversion"**

Someone can help a newbie ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are printing array as as string.

> returning result of `\Db::select` is an array so to print array you can use `print_r()`

```php
$results = \Db::select('select * from engegraph_forms_membros where id = ?', [1]);
echo '<pre/>'; print_r($result); exit();
```

you can print result like this or you can use build in debugger function.

```php
$results = \Db::select('select * from engegraph_forms_membros where id = ?', [1]);
dd($result);
// or dump($result);
```

> if you use `dump/dd` function you dont need to worry it can print anything. `dd [die and dump]` stops php flow to next statements. `dump` will continues flow so you can print another values/or/execute next statements if you need.

if any doubts please add comments.

Comment: I want send the result to update my partial but i dont have sucess yet